# Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable

Tags: android

I've successfully installed the Intel HAXM and was working fine on my computer. After formatting my computer and again installing the same version of Android SDK I'm facing this problem again and again. The configuration of my computer is
2.5 GB RAM, Intel Dual Core 1.46GHz processor in my HP Compaq Presario C700. Window7 Professional 32bits.

**The error I'm getting is:**

**emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Android Emulator requires an Intel processor with VT-x and NX support.  (VT-x is not supported)**

Please help me in this regard as I'm new in Android.

Comment: Since you say that the CPU clock is 1.46 GHz I'm going to assume that your CPU is the Intel Core Duo T2310. Looking at [Intel's information page for said CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/32431/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T2310-1M-Cache-1_46-GHz-533-MHz-FSB) tells us that the CPU doesn't support VT-x.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you try to run an ARM AVD instead of an x86 AVD? If not, that could be a workaround unless you absolutely need to test your app on an x86 device.

Comment: As you already stated the answer it say "VT-x is not supported",  But you can check around your BIOS configuration, if there is any option for virtualization or HAMX, if yes turn them on.

Answer (score 0):

If your driver not already installed go to step 2,

1-Fully Uninstall HAXm driver from Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager path by running intelhaxm-android.exe then select remove

2-Download older version driver from this link:
https://intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-man2.software.informer.com/download/

3-Unzip the downloaded archive haxm-windows_v7_5_1.zip

4-Enter to extracted files then run intelhaxm-android.exe

5-Follow step by step by pressing next

6-Finally enjoy installing HAXM driver!!